# Javascript Checkbox select/unselect

Tags: javascript

Im using java script in JSP the problem is i need auto refresh on selectin checkbox it's working fine but on unselecting it's not stopping the auto refresh activity .plz suggest 
Thanks in advance

```
function autorefresh() {
    var isChecked = document.getElementById("is_check").checked;
    var time = 0;
    if (isChecked == true) {
        time = setInterval(function () {
            showExport()
        }, 5000);
    } else if (isChecked == false) {
        clearInterval(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare `time` outside of the function. Also note that you can reduce `if (x == true) {...} else if (x == false) {...}` to `if (x) {...} else {...}`.

Comment: @FelixKling - Why? And by the way @NaimFS, `setInterval(function () { showExport() }, 5000);` --> `setInterval(showExport, 5000);`

Comment: So that it persists between function calls.

Comment: @FelixKling - Is it because `autorefresh` is called multiple times? (although he never said it in his question or I missed it probably)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: I assume so. I thought it would be called when the state of the checkbox changes. But that of course might be a misinterpretation on my side. Of course if the function is only called once, then the problem is that changing the state of the checkbox doesn't trigger a reevaluation (but he would still have to store the ID outside of the function somewhere).

Comment: @FelixKling - I don't believe that `autorefresh` is recalled every time because then `setInterval` will also be re-executed. (if he *is* though, then he should fix it...)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Why, it makes total sense: If the checkbox is checked, start the interval. If it is unchecked, stop it, etc. Of course it should be reexecuted when the checkbox is checked again.

Comment: @FelixKling - Oh wait, you are right. Everything makes sense now. Looks like I should go get some sleep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define time variable as global:

```
window.time=0;     //global declaration
function autorefresh() {
    var isChecked = document.getElementById("is_check").checked;
    if (isChecked == true) {
        time = setInterval(function () {
            showExport()
        }, 5000);
    } else if (isChecked == false) {
        clearInterval(time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are defining the `time` variable inside the `autorefresh` context, so it no longer stores the ID of the interval, you should define it outside of the function.